# Difference between Wildcard certificate with Subject Alternative Name and without Subject Alternative Name

Tags: ssl, cacerts, subject-alternative-name

What is the difference between Wildcard certificate with Subject Alternative Name and without Subject Alternative Name.

Is there any security implications in regards to Wildcard certificate with subject-alternate-name?

Comment: The question doesn't make sense. The wildcarded domain name must be one of the subject alternative names. The use of the CN field of the Subject for this purpose was deprecated decades ago.

Comment: A certificate without a subject alternative name is invalid for use in securing an SSL connection.  [Using the subject DN/CN to identify a certificate has been deprecated.  Since 2000.  Literally.](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2818)